# Shouldn't it be 'Scheduled for Demolition' and not 'Under Demolition''?

Tags: word-choice

There is a building beside my office with a sign board

> *This building is **under** demolition*

And, this is the sign I have been observing since past 6 months (and who knows for coming months or years)! If I read *Demolition in progress, keep away* **OR** This building is *scheduled for demolition*, I had no problem in understanding that.

Facts apart (whether the builders are in processes or whatever), I'm concerned about **the language English here.**

Can we use the word ***'under'*** for something that is ***not happening*** right in front of you? The **process is not ON** and nobody knows when it'll be. If I say "under 'x'" all of you will certainly take it as it's **in progress.** We all know...

> This road is **under** construction- you see the road is **getting done**, you may find people working on this as well 
>   This building is **under construction** - you see *some* constructed part or people working on it.

So, in these latter cases, you clearly find **evidence** of 'X' in *Under [X].* but this is not true in case of **under demolition.**

Also, are they using the word correctly? Demolition or destruction?

Comment: Perhaps it is okay, considering that we have "Demolition in progress" signs. But 6 months, really!

Comment: That creates an ambiguity - *under demolition* or *demolition in progress*

Comment: @DamkerngT. no no... I think you din' get it. The building is **intact** but just seems scheduled for demolition. The building is evacuated and lying in dust, closed.

Comment: I might misunderstand it, but I don't think that *demolition* is punctual. It might sound punctual, but just like many other things in life, several things need to be prepared and done before the actual "demolition" event. I don't know about others, but I would have a "Demolition in progress" sign shown since day one.

Comment: True but I'm concerned about using the word *under* with *demolish*. If *under* is used with construction, you see the evidecnes, the progress but here, there's no progress. It's just planned. When the progress is ON, I'm okay with any sign board the question arises when the process is still **not** on.

Comment: Couldn't it simply be that they _did_ start, and the first thing was to put up the sign - and then the project was delayed or cancelled. Then the only problem is that nobody cared enough to remove or change the sign, but that would be hardly surprising :) I have seen many things "under construction" without any measurable progress for long periods of time, by the way.

Comment: quite practical answer than grammatical ;) +1

Comment: Grammar has its uses, but in case of big projects, pragmaticality often works better ;)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it looks like a peeve. Besides, for all we know, the demolition process may have started months ago (perhaps internal parts were removed, leaving the building in an unstable/unsafe state). The rest of the process may have been (intentionally or unexpectedly) delayed for any amount of time.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I cannot help you with your way of looking my past couple of questions. To others, it's simple to understand though as they probably understand my concern. A good and motivating answer would have been - *No, I think if it reads 'under demolition', the demolition must have begun somewhere but not be visible. Anything 'under' in such context means the process is on* (As I learned from the answers and comments here). But anyway, as I said, difficult to change a *personal* view of anyone. You reported closing, but I hope others understand it as they have been till now.

Comment: @FumbleFingers One more thing, I could not understand the meaning of *a peeve* in this context. :) I searched dictionaries but could not relate that term with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As oerkelens comments, the term *under demolition* implies 'undergoing the demolition process, including all associated processes', rather than just the literal 'being blown up, right now, at this moment in time'.

In addition to the already supplied reasons for what looks like no demolition activity occcuring (asbestos removal, interior structure being removed etc). It is possible that at the last moment, some protest happened that made them decide to reconsider the demolition.  Until this reconsideration has finished, they may find it easier to just leave the sign in place.

With regard to demolition vs destruction.  These are similar enough that either would be acceptable, though demolish is more precise.  (Googling the definition of the two words shows these common synonyms:  knock down, pull down, tear down.  Additionally they are synonyms of each other.)  Demolished is the more specific of the two as most definitions imply a **building** being pulled or torn down, whereas destruction is the end of existence of **anything** but the end result of a demolition is that something has been destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

You are quite right. Signwriters are no better than greengrocers. Rather than seek out the wretch responsible, take a photo of the offending sign and post it on this page at Pinterest.

https://www.pinterest.com/pin/78883430946261237/

I keep meaning to post a pic of "This door is alarmed" which I see so often nowadays.

Comment: I keep meaning to put a sign on my door saying *"This door is shitting itself"*. I think if you want to get the message across to potential burglars, you gotta use the kind of words they would.

Comment: *This door is somewhat perturbed*

Answer (score 0):

First, realize that in that context, a sign at a construction site, the poster is in no way concerned with accuracy or correctness.  All they want you to know is that building is coming down, eventually.

Take that phrase specifically and there are some inferences you can make:

1. This building is under Demolition Order.  Meaning a government agency has ordered it's demolition or a demolition permit has been granted.
2. There may be non-visible demolition work underway inside the building.  Asbestos removal for example.
3. Demolition started, but is delayed now for some reason.

Destruction implies an adverse or undesirable situation and wouldn't be appropriate here.